# Generate dynamic SCSS Variables

Tags: sass

I like the way Tailwind defines the colors and would like to use that outside of a Tailwind project.

For that I have defined two colors that I am already generating as classes (bg-|text-):

I would like to (if possible) generate the appropriate SCSS variables.
e.g. `$blue-300: #183f6d;`

Is that possible?

```
$tailwind-colors: ("blue-900": #183f6d, "blue-300": #c4cddd);

@each $name, $hexcode in $tailwind-colors {
    
  // Generate Variables
  // #{$name}: $hexcode; <--- 

  // Generate Classes
  .hover\:text-#{$name}:hover,
  .text-#{$name} {
    color: $hexcode;
  }

  .hover\:bg-#{$name}:hover,
  .bg-#{$name} {
    background-color: $hexcode;
  }
}
```

[Sass Manual](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps)

[Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jolution/5be59306edcb8e65f5ef5a13b6070a05)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response to my request from [@SassCSS](https://twitter.com/SassCSS) on Twitter:

> Sass intentionally doesn't support this, because it makes it very hard
> for both people and the compiler to figure out where a given variable
> comes from. We recommend explicitly accessing the map using map.get()
> instead

Source: [Tweet](https://twitter.com/SassCSS/status/1407229715673325570?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1407229715673325570%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_c10&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fpublish.twitter.com%2F%3Fquery%3Dhttps3A2F2Ftwitter.com2FSassCSS2Fstatus2F1407229715673325570widget%3DTweet)

The solution for me, is therefore to create the variables as SCSS variables and then use them there:

```
// Syntax: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors
$bg-blue-900: #004070;
$bg-blue-700: #537AA2;
$bg-blue-300: #C1CCDD;
$bg-blue-50: #EAEDF3;
$white: #FFF;
$black: #000;

// Define Tailwind Colors
$tailwind-colors: (
    "white": $white,
    "black": $black,
    "blue-900": $bg-blue-900,
    "blue-700": $bg-blue-700,
    "blue-300": $bg-blue-300,
    "blue-50": $bg-blue-50
);
```

The other way around it would then also work with map-get:

```
//@debug map-get($tailwind-colors, white);
//$white: map-get($tailwind-colors, "white");
```

Source: [map-get](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if you do it as a separate function inside the `:root` element of your SCSS file.

```css
$tailwind-colors: ("blue-300": #183f6d, "blue-900": #c4cddd);

// Generate Variables
:root {
  @each $name, $hexcode in $tailwind-colors {
    --#{$name}: #{$hexcode};
  }
}

@each $name, $hexcode in $tailwind-colors {
  // Generate Classes
  .text-#{$name} {
    color: $hexcode;
  }

  .bg-#{$name} {
    background-color: $hexcode;
  }
}
```

This will result in formatted CSS:

```css
:root {
  --blue-300: #183f6d;
  --blue-900: #c4cddd;
}

.text-blue-300 {
  color: #183f6d;
}

.bg-blue-300 {
  background-color: #183f6d;
}

.text-blue-900 {
  color: #c4cddd;
}

.bg-blue-900 {
  background-color: #c4cddd;
}
```

See [this CodePen example](https://codepen.io/donroyco/pen/ZEerbdg) where you can see the compiled CSS with the dropdown button right top.

[image: Dropdown menu CodePen]

Comment: Thank you very much Roy. This is a good approach and also practical in the project. Unfortunately, I actually need the variable to access it within SCSS. Nevertheless, thank you very much!